# Rails automatically load lib from beginning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create a `awsmail.rb` inside `lib` directory.

```
class AwsMail
  def...
end
```

However, when I called it on `rails console`, it threw this error.

```
pry(main)> AwsMail
NameError: uninitialized constant AwsMail
```

I need to load this file by myself, so that it can be called.

Like this.

```
pry(main)> load "#{Rails.root}/lib/awsmail.rb"
=> true
pry(main)> AwsMail
=> AwsMail
```

How do I make this file automatically being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a class has a name like `AwsMail` then file should be `aws_mail.rb`.

Check the good blog post [`Rails autoloading — how it works, and when it doesn't`](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/#file-lookup-rules)

> In contrast with Ruby’s autoload, which requires the location of each
>   autoloaded constant to be specified in advance, **Rails follows a simple
>   convention that maps constant names to filenames.** Nesting corresponds
>   to directories, and constant names are underscored:

```
MyModule::SomeClass # => my_module/some_class.rb
```

Also dont forget to add a `lib` folder to the autoload path.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add it to the `autoload_path` in the `config/application.rb`, like:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```